# InfoWindow отображаются в стороне (Google Maps API)

Tags: google-maps-api

`InfoWindow` Google Maps отображаются не над маркером, а в стороне, и с содержимым последнего.

...добавляю маркеры на карту из массива:

```
for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    var ll = objects[i].coordinates.split(',');
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(ll[0], ll[1]);
    var address = [];
    address = objects[i].address;
    if (distHaversine(latlng, circleOptions.center) < radius) {
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: address
        });
        objects_markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:latlng,
            clickable:true,
            map: map,
            title: address,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            visible: true,
            icon: 'images/beachflag.png'
        });
        objects_markers[i].addListener('click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, objects_markers[i]);
        });
    }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо:

`objects_markers[i].addListener('click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, objects_markers[i]);
        });`

Заменить на:

`setInfoWindowHandlers(i);`

И добавить функцию: `function setInfoWindowHandlers(i) {
  objects_markers[i].addListener('click', function() {
    console.log(i);
    infowindow[i].open(map, objects_markers[i]);
  });
}`